Slider repeat not good
I have a problem with slider.
First 4 picture good, from right move to left. But when repeating slider, everything bad, actual picture went left, but new picture come from left.
I tried to reset sliders, not work, or I don't know how..
Do you have any idea?
<style>
  ...
</style> 

<section>

 <div id="slider-container">
  <!-- 1. slide -->
  <div class="slider active" style="background-image: url('assets/images/img-3824-1800x1350.jpg');">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h5>Nappali</h5>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- 2. slide -->
  ...
  </div>
  
  <!-- 3. slide -->
...

  <!-- 4. slide -->
  ...
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  let slides = $('#slider-container .slider');
  let currentIndex = 0;

  function goToSlide(index) {

    slides.eq(index).css('left', '0%');
     slides.eq(index-1).css('left', '-100%');
      currentIndex = index;

  }

  function nextSlide() {
    let nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % slides.length;
    goToSlide(nextIndex);
  }

  function prevSlide() {
    let prevIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + slides.length) % slides.length;
    goToSlide(prevIndex);
  }

  setInterval(nextSlide, 2000); 
});

</script>

</section>

Thanks,
Adrian

Hi, @AdrianVarga, does this work the way you intend? https://www.mediafire.com/file/ws3fr2d0bnodpnt/slideshow.html/file If so, it looks like your problem was an off-by-one error with the slide indices. If the file I linked doesn't do what you want, please edit your question to add more detail about the sequence of events you want vs. what you're actually getting. (If my demonstration does solve your problem, you'll probably want to close this question as "not reproducible or caused by a typo.")
